# Remove/Toggle Divs

Tags: jquery

How do remove a div by clicking on it, but hide or display any of the divs with name or age in the ID.

One checkbox should toggle any divs with "name" at the beginning of the ID, and another checkbox should toggle any divs with "age"at the beginning of the ID

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="name-254"></div>
  <div id="age-645"></div>
  <div id="name-142"></div>
  <div id="name-341"></div>
  <div id="age-341"></div>
  <div id="name-341"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are your checkboxes? Are we supposed to do that for you too?

Comment: It would also help you to accept answers of people who have answered your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the `div` elements self-destruct when you click on them you could do the following:

```
// Inside the #container, when somebody clicks a div
$("#container").on("click", "div", function(){
   // Remove that div
   $(this).remove(); 
});​​​​​
```

As for checkboxes that toggle the visibility of each set:

```
// When somebody clicks on a checkbox
$(":checkbox").on("click", function(){
    // Reference for the checkbox, its name, and checked property (true|false)
    var chbx = $(this),
        name = chbx.attr("name"), 
        show = chbx.prop("checked");

    // Find elements whose id begins with the checkbox name
    // and set their toggle to true or false
    $("[id^=" + name + "]").toggle( show );
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/6GBpW/3/

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to multi delete? Display checked next to each div after clicking anouther div that will show/hide the delete checkboxes?

Comment: @user826855 It's possible, but that is an entirely different question. Please feel free to round up all of the details (and a sketch/demo if possible) and ask a new question.